# Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent variable with mpdf $f_X(x) = 1 \space and \space f_Y(y) = 1$

Tags: probability, statistics

I couldn't figure out the solution to this exercise and after having a look at the solution, I'm unsure towards my understanding of it. I would appreciate some helpful interpretations on how to understand the integral.

Q. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables, whose marginal pdfs are given below. Find the pdf of $X$ + $Y$. (Hint: Consider two cases, $0 < w < 1$ and $1 < w < 2$
$f_X(x) = 1$, $0 \le x \le 1$, and $f_Y(y) = 1$, $0 \le y \le 1$

Solution:

- First suppose that $0 \le w \le 1$ is the integral from $w$ to $0$, so $\int_0^w(1)(1)dx = w$, $\color{red}{why?}$. Now consider the case $1 \le w \le 2$. Here, the first integrand vanishes unless $x \le 1$, $\color{red}{why?}$. Also, the second pdf is $0$ unless $w-x \le 1$ or $x \ge w-1$, $\color{red}{why?}$. Then $f_{X+Y}(w) = \int_{w-1}^1(1)(1)dx = 2-w$

Essentially, I am unsure of those three statements that are made and would really appreciate some clarification by the community.

Comment: Try and draw a diagram. Also try and find $F_W(w)$ and then differentiate for density if this is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several methods to find the pdf of $Z=X+Y$ but consider that you can set the following system

$$
\begin{cases}
z=x+y \\
u=x
\end{cases}$$

that is

$$
\begin{cases}
x=u \\
y=z-u
\end{cases}$$

To change the variable  you have to calculate the Jacobian, which is evidently 1, and thus the new joint density is

$$f_{UZ}(u,z)=1$$

The key to solve the exercise is to understand what is the new support of the vector $(U,Z)$ and to do that, please observe that

$$y=z-u$$

being $y \in (0;1)$ it is also

$$0<z-u<1$$

plotting this double inequality you find that the joint support is the following purple parallelogram

[image]

And thus to find $f_Z(z)$ you simply have to integrate in $du$, horizontally...now I think all should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the integral you are using is the convolution:$$f_{\small X+Y}(w) =\int_\Bbb R f_{\small X}(x)\,f_{\small Y}(w-x)\,\mathrm d x$$

Now $f_{\small X}(x) = \mathbf 1_{0<x<1}$ and $f_{\small Y}(w-x) = \mathbf 1_{0<w-x<1}$ , which gives us the support for $f_{\small X+Y}(w)$ and the domain of the integral relative to the value of the argument ($w$).

$$\begin{align}f_{\small X}(x)\,f_{\small Y}(w-x) &= \mathbf 1_{0<w<2}\,\mathbf 1_{(0<x<1)\land(w-1<x<w)}\\[1ex]&=\mathbf 1_{0<w<2}\,\mathbf 1_{\max\{0,w-1\}<x<\min\{1,w\}}\\[1ex]&=\mathbf 1_{0<w<1}\,\mathbf 1_{0<x<w}+\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant w<2}\,\mathbf 1_{w-1<x<1}\end{align}$$

**That is to argue:**

The pdf of $X+Y$ will be supported on $(0..2)$ and the integration (w.r.t. $x$ for a given $w$) will be over the intersection of $(0..1)$ and $(w-1..w)$.   So when $w\in(0..1)$ then we integrate over $(0..w)$ and when $w\in[1..2)$ we integrate over $(w-1..1)$

---

**In summary:**

$$\begin{align}f_{\small X+Y}(w) &=\int_\Bbb R f_{\small X}(x)\,f_{\small Y}(w-x)\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&=\int_\Bbb R \mathbf 1_{0<x<1}\,\mathbf 1_{0<w-x<1}\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&=\mathbf 1_{0<w<2}\int_{\max\{0,w-1\}}^{\min\{1,w\}}\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&=\mathbf 1_{0<w<1}\int_0^w\,\mathrm d x+\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant w<2}\int_{w-1}^1\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex] &= w\,\mathbf 1_{0<w<1}+(2-w)\,\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant w<2}\end{align}$$

---

**NB:**

$\mathbf 1_{0<x<1}$ is an *indicator function*, which equals $1$ when the subscript holds, and $0$ otherwise. $$\mathbf 1_{0<x<1}=\begin{cases}1&:& 0<x<1\\0&:& \textsf{otherwise}\end{cases}$$